# drag the mouse down when clicking

Tags: c#, onclick, mouseclick-event, mouseleftbuttondown

I have been trying to make a script that drags your mouse down when you left click.
So far my code looks like this (just for the test I have been using the Write "1" part)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        while (Console.ReadKey(false).Key == ConsoleKey.LeftWindows)
            Console.Write("1");
    }
}
```

Now I know that `LeftWindows` is not the left mousebutton. I just had no idea.

Comment: Why are you making a console application? Why not make WinForms or WPF? I don't believe you can manipulate the mouse in a console app.

Comment: I really don't understand how your code is related to your question.

Comment: well i thought if you can switch on and off stuff with keys why not control the mouse. Thats why i did that. you could be right. i can try that.

Comment: @FabioMarcolini well I am looking to make a script that drags the mouse down, but sofar i dont even know the event of a left mouse button click

Comment: Man I'd get so pissed if my mouse moved every time i clicked it.

Comment: @Jonesy This is for anti recoil in certain games :)

Comment: [Here's a start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497024/how-to-detect-mouse-clicks). you're wanting to grab *all* clicks, not just within your application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't think you can  get mouse events only from your program,
you will have to hook to the global mouse events.
That means that you'll be notified about EVERY mouse event in the system.
You can hook to global mouse events like this:
[Global mouse event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607133/global-mouse-event-handler)

When you receive WM_LBUTTONDOWN, it means that the left button was pressed.
Then you can move the mouse like this:
[How to move mouse cursor using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050825/how-to-move-mouse-cursor-using-c)

(I recommend that your handling code will be done in another thread than the one which captures to mouse events. Otherwise, you might miss events.)

Comment: this helped me a lot! i have it moving my mouse down now. thank you!