# WPF CaptureMouse does not capture mouse events outside of the main window

Tags: wpf, mouse

I've created a trivial WPF application that tries to capture the mouse, but it stops getting mousemove events after the mouse leaves the window.  Strangely, I do get a mouseup event outside the window.

I've tried a  couple variants of mousecapture, but nothing works.  I've also tried watching for MouseLost event and I don't see it when the mouse goes outside of the window.  It just see it when I release the mouse button.

Here is my MainWindow class.   I get Mouse move events as long as the mouse is in the window, but if I click and drag the mouse out of the window, I stop getting move events.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MouseDown += MainWindow_MouseDown;
            MouseUp += MainWindow_MouseUp;
            MouseMove += MainWindow_MouseMove;
            LostMouseCapture += MainWindow_LostMouseCapture;
        }

        private void MainWindow_LostMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Lost Mouse");
        }

        private void MainWindow_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("P: " + Mouse.GetPosition(this));
        }

        private void MainWindow_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Releasing");
            ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }

        private void MainWindow_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Capturing");
            CaptureMouse();
            // This does not work either: Mouse.Capture(this, CaptureMode.SubTree);
        }

    }
```

I am expecting to see all the mousemove events so that I can drag the window, but I only see the mouseup event outside, and the mousemoves only happen if the cursor is inside the window.

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. If you want to capture mouse moves outside of your application window,  you need to hook into the global events: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120848/wpf-catch-user-mouse-movement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, I have an answer for this question.  WPF applications can't see the mouse when it leaves the app window, so if you want to have some custom dragging behavior it is necessary to use interrop to capture the mouse globally.   I created the following class to enable DPI-aware window dragging across multiple monitors for any WPF window:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

[assembly: DisableDpiAwareness]

namespace Talisman
{

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>
    /// Enables dragging of a WPF window in a way that is per-monitor DPI sensitive.
    /// 
    /// HOW TO USE
    /// Add a DraggingLogic member variable and put this code in your window constructor:
    ///     _draggingLogic = new DraggingLogic(this);
    ///     
    /// If you want to do special things when the window moves or when it is clicked:
    ///     _draggingLogic.OnPositionChanged += (xm, ym) => {/* whatever you want here */};
    ///     _draggingLogic.OnClick += () => {/* whatever you want here */};
    ///
    /// </summary>
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public class DraggingLogic
    {
        public event Action<double, double> OnPositionChanged;
        public event Action OnClick;

        /// <summary>
        /// Factor to convert Horizontal screen coordinates
        /// </summary>
        public double DpiCorrectionX { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Factor to convertVertical  screen coordinates
        /// </summary>
        public double DpiCorrectionY { get; set; }

        public double WpfDpiX { get; set; }
        public double WpfDpiY { get; set; }

        #region INTERROP - Mouse interaction

        private static int _mouseHookHandle;
        private delegate int HookProc(int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        private static HookProc _mouseDelegate;

        private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;
        private const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
        private const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct POINT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
        {
            public POINT pt;
            public uint mouseData;
            public uint flags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, int dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
           CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int UnhookWindowsHookEx(int idHook);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
             CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern int CallNextHookEx(int idHook, int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string name);

        #endregion

        #region INTERROP - DPI

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MonitorFromPoint([In]System.Drawing.Point pt, [In]uint dwFlags);

        [DllImport("Shcore.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetDpiForMonitor([In]IntPtr hmonitor, [In]DpiType dpiType, [Out]out uint dpiX, [Out]out uint dpiY);
        [DllImport("Shcore.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SetProcessDpiAwareness([In]DpiAwareness dpiAwareness); 

        public enum DpiType
        {
            Effective = 0,
            Angular = 1,
            Raw = 2,
        }

        public enum DpiAwareness
        {
            Unaware = 0,
            System = 1,
            PerMonitor = 2,
        }

        #endregion

        Screen _currentScreen;
        Window _dragMe;
        bool _dragging = false;
        double _dragDelta = 0;
        Point _lastMousePosition;
        Point _mouseStickyPosition;

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Get resource text using a loose naming scheme
        /// </summary>
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public DraggingLogic(Window dragme)
        {
            var result = SetProcessDpiAwareness(DpiAwareness.PerMonitor);
            dragme.MouseDown += HandleMouseDown;
            dragme.MouseMove += HandleMouseMove;
            dragme.MouseUp += HandleMouseUp;
            dragme.Loaded += Dragme_Loaded;
            _dragMe = dragme;
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Dragme_Loaded - can't find DPI until the window is loaded
        /// </summary>
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private void Dragme_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(_dragMe);
            WpfDpiX = 96.0 * source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;
            WpfDpiY = 96.0 * source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M22;
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Figure out scaling for the DPI on a certain monitor
        /// </summary>
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void CalculateDpiScaleFactors(Screen screen, DpiType dpiType)
        {
            var point = new System.Drawing.Point(screen.Bounds.Left + 1, screen.Bounds.Top + 1);
            var monitor = MonitorFromPoint(point, 2/*MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST*/);
            Debug.WriteLine($"Monitor: {monitor}");
            var result = GetDpiForMonitor(monitor, dpiType, out var monitorDpiX, out var monitorDpiY);
            if(result != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                monitorDpiX = monitorDpiY = 96;
            }
            DpiCorrectionX = 96.0 / monitorDpiX;
            DpiCorrectionY = 96.0 / monitorDpiY;
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Mouse Down
        /// </summary>
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private void HandleMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = sender as Window;
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {

                _dragging = true;
                _dragDelta = 0;
                _mouseStickyPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(window);
                _lastMousePosition = window.PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(window));
                _currentScreen = GetScreenFromPoint(_lastMousePosition);
                CalculateDpiScaleFactors(_currentScreen, DpiType.Effective);

                CaptureGlobalMouse();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Mouse Move
        /// </summary>
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private void HandleMouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_dragging)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// HandleGlobalMouseMove
        /// </summary>
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private void HandleGlobalMouseMove(Point mouseLocation)
        {
            var newPosition = mouseLocation; // This arrives without DPI correction
            var screen = GetScreenFromPoint(newPosition);

            // We need to do some fix up when we drag to another screen because
            // the DPI on the other screen could be different
            if(screen != null &&  screen.DeviceName != _currentScreen.DeviceName)
            {
                CalculateDpiScaleFactors(screen, DpiType.Effective);
                _lastMousePosition = newPosition;

                // Move the window to match the mouse position
                _dragMe.Left = (newPosition.X - _mouseStickyPosition.X)* DpiCorrectionX;
                _dragMe.Top = (newPosition.Y - _mouseStickyPosition.Y)* DpiCorrectionY;
                _currentScreen = screen;
            }

            var xMove = (newPosition.X - _lastMousePosition.X)* DpiCorrectionX;
            var yMove = (newPosition.Y - _lastMousePosition.Y)* DpiCorrectionY;
            _dragMe.Left += xMove;
            _dragMe.Top += yMove;
            _dragDelta += (_lastMousePosition - newPosition).Length;
            _lastMousePosition = newPosition;
            OnPositionChanged?.Invoke(xMove, yMove);
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// GetScreenFromPoint - return the screen from a raw point (presumably mouse coordinate)
        /// </summary>
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public Screen GetScreenFromPoint(Point point)
        {
            foreach (Screen screen in Screen.AllScreens)
            {
                if (screen.ContainsPoint(point.X, point.Y)) return screen;
            }
            return null;
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Mouse Up
        /// </summary>
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private void HandleMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_dragging)
            {
                var window = sender as Window;
                // if the user didn't actually drag, then we want to treat this as a click
                if (_dragDelta < 3)
                {
                    OnClick?.Invoke();
                }
                _dragging = false;
                ReleaseGlobalMouse();
                if(e != null) e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// MouseHookProc- allows us to handle global mouse events
        /// </summary>
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private int MouseHookProc(int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0)
            {
                switch (wParam)
                {
                    case WM_LBUTTONUP: HandleMouseUp(this, null); break;
                    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                        {
                            var mouseHookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
                            HandleGlobalMouseMove(new Point(mouseHookStruct.pt.x, mouseHookStruct.pt.y));
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_mouseHookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// CaptureGlobalMouse
        /// </summary>
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private void CaptureGlobalMouse()
        {
            if (_mouseHookHandle == 0)
            {
                _mouseDelegate = MouseHookProc;
                _mouseHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL,
                    _mouseDelegate,
                    GetModuleHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName),
                    0);
                if (_mouseHookHandle == 0)
                {
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }
            }
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// ReleaseGlobalMouse
        /// </summary>
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private void ReleaseGlobalMouse()
        {
            if (_mouseHookHandle != 0)
            {
                int result = UnhookWindowsHookEx(_mouseHookHandle);
                _mouseHookHandle = 0;
                _mouseDelegate = null;
                if (result == 0)
                {
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know its being a while, but do you remember how exactly WPF knows it should ignore `WM_MOUSEMOVE` when mouse is outside the window?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use mouse capture on the object itself so in `MouseDown` you want `((IInputElement)sender).CaptureMouse()` and in `MouseUp` `((IInputElement)sender).ReleaseMouseCapture()`.

Alternatively, you can also use `MainWindow.CaptureMouse()`.

```cs
private void MainWindow_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Releasing");
    ((IInputElement)sender).ReleaseMouseCapture();
}

private void MainWindow_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Capturing");
    ((IInputElement)sender).CaptureMouse();
    // This does not work either: Mouse.Capture(this, CaptureMode.SubTree);
}
```